# Connected to the Internet using a tethered iPhone yet the Wi-Fi hotspot is visible

Tags: windows-7, iphone, hotspot

For having a more secure connection, I tethered my iPhone directly to my Windows 7 Pro 64 bit PC.

If I switch off the hot-spot I lose my connection, but when it is on, I can see my iPhone’s Wi-Fi in the list of available Wi-Fi networks where I can connect. I guess everybody else can see it too. I found this to be strange.

Is there a way to tether the iPhone without having to turn on the hotspot?